# Tablesorter Export to Excel Plugin or Small Script Exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I would like to know if there is any plugin or a simple/small script for tablesorter that would export all of the columns and rows to excel with a click of a button. I tried to search online for it but I didn't find anything.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because modern browsers are ["sandboxed"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_%28computer_security%29), you will need some sort of program to do file downloads via purely client-side JavaScript.  I use [downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/downloadify) and find it suits my needs quite well.  It's not a true plug-in for tablesorter, but can easily work side-by-side with it.